# Has anyone ever played and recorded a full game of Taikyoku Shogi?

Tags: famous-games, shogi

I have googled for a little while and found [pages](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiuktnRg_DVAhUJPFAKHXwUDNAQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTaikyoku_shogi&usg=AFQjCNFpMBva96MQDb1auqQXaZQ4-HW70g) [and](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiuktnRg_DVAhUJPFAKHXwUDNAQFghFMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chessvariants.com%2Fshogivariants.dir%2Ftaikyoku_english.html&usg=AFQjCNGOTrm5THbmRQT114pKY4c6Pt7c7A) [pages](https://www.revolvy.com/topic/Taikyoku%20shogi) [of](http://schnee.livejournal.com/1759360.html) rules and explanations but no documentation. Are there **any** documented games where the moves have been recorded? It's so ridiculous, I don't believe that anyone has ever been able to finish a game, let alone remember all of the piece movements.

[image]

Comment: I used to have a *Tai Shogi* (25x25) program on my computer. I was usually able to finish a game in about 3 hours because the engine was really bad.

Comment: It is good that there is no drop rule in taikyoku shogi, otherwise the game length will be more prolonged.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is yes.
According to [jawp article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%B1%80%E5%B0%86%E6%A3%8B), a game of Taikyoku Shogi was played for Japanese TV show "Tribia-no-Izumi" (=Fountain of trivia), broadcast on 19th May 2004.  The game continued 32 hours 41 minutes and 3805 moves before the first player won.  This seems to be the first full-recorded game of the variant.
Also, there is [a webpage](http://taikyokushogi.pv.land.to/)
dedicated to Taikyoku Shogi with a playing webservice（大局FLASH, requiring Flash Player）.